# Get last day of month :: Expression language evaluation error :${coord:dateOffset(${coord:endOfMonths(0)}, -1, 'DAY')}:

Tags: oozie

I want to get last day of previous month and don't understand where is the error

```
<value>${coord:formatTime(${coord:dateOffset(${coord:endOfMonths(0)}, -1, 'DAY')}, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}</value>
```

Comment: Remove the inner `${ }` . `${...}` means evaluate the inner expression,, inside text,

Comment: Unfortunately, even ${coord:dateOffset(coord:endOfMonths(0), -1,'DAY')} doesn't want to work, there is error in endOfMonths(0) that returns a list, not a single value I guess

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with _oozie_.